ImportError: cannot import name 'FirecrawlApp' from partially initialized module 'firecrawl' (most likely due to a circular import)
I'm trying to use Firecrawl to scrape a webpage, but I'm encountering a circular import error. Here's my code:
from firecrawl import FirecrawlApp
from openai import OpenAI
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
import json
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
def scrape_data(url):
    load_dotenv()
    # Initialize the FirecrawlApp with your API key
    app = FirecrawlApp(api_key=os.getenv('FIRECRAWL_API_KEY'))
    
    # Scrape a single URL
    scraped_data = app.scrape_url(url, {'pageOptions': {'onlyMainContent': True}})
    
    # Check if 'markdown' key exists in the scraped data
    if 'markdown' in scraped_data:
        return scraped_data['markdown']
    else:
        raise KeyError("The key 'markdown' does not exist in the scraped data.")

When I run this code, I get the following error:
ImportError: cannot import name 'FirecrawlApp' from partially initialized module 'firecrawl' (most likely due to a circular import)

I've checked my imports and code structure, but I'm not sure what's causing the circular import error. Can anyone help me resolve this issue and successfully import FirecrawlApp from the firecrawl module?

This question was asked a few months ago, but I still thought to post here.
The Firecrawl Python SDK changed in the meantime a little bit. Using v1, the pageOptions key is invalid. The rest of the code you can see below is identical to the one provided in the question above.
example.py
import os
from firecrawl import FirecrawlApp
from dotenv import load_dotenv


def scrape_data(url):
    load_dotenv()
    # Initialize the FirecrawlApp with your API key
    app = FirecrawlApp(api_key=os.getenv("FIRECRAWL_API_KEY"))

    # Scrape a single URL
    scraped_data = app.scrape_url(url, params={"onlyMainContent": True})

    # Check if 'markdown' key exists in the scraped data
    if "markdown" in scraped_data:
        return scraped_data["markdown"]
    else:
        raise KeyError("The key 'markdown' does not exist in the scraped data.")


print(scrape_data("https://www.firecrawl.dev/"))

Running example.py gives an output as expected:
All of our yearly plans get 2 months free! [Check it out ](/pricing)

[Get 2 months free with yearly plan](/pricing)

# Turn websites into   _LLM-ready_ data

Power your AI apps with clean data crawled from any website. It's also open-source.

Start for free (500 credits)Start for free

A product by

[![Mendable Logo](/images/mendable_logo_transparent.png)Mendable](https://mendable.ai)

![Example Webpage](/multiple-websites.png)

## Crawl, Scrape, Clean

We crawl all accessible subpages and give you clean markdown for each. No sitemap required.

...

This most probably implies that the error you're getting is caused by the rest of the code you haven't shared in the question above.
